# sbtEclipse giving error with lagom project

Tags: java, eclipse, sbt, lagom

I have downloaded the latest version of activator (1.3.9), and trying to get a Lagom project up and running using this guideline (http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/GettingStarted.html)

I got a new lagom-java project (using the activator new command). I am able to run activator command successfully in the project directory, but when I try to run eclipse in the activator console, I get the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Undefined setting 'eclipseSkipProject in Scope(Select(ProjectRef(file:/C:/code/microservices/first-ms/,lagom-internal-meta-project-service-locator)),This,This,This)'!
```

I have the following entries in 'project/eclipse.sbt':

`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")`

And the following in project/plugins.sbt:

```
    addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.lagom" % "lagom-sbt-plugin" % "1.0.0-M1")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-lagom-bundle" % "1.0.2")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.conductr" % "sbt-conductr-sandbox" % "1.4.2")
```

I know that 'lagom-internal-meta-project-service-locator' is an internal project not to be imported into eclipse, but not sure from where it is picking up eclipseSkipProject setting, as I have not defined 'skipProject' in build.sbt anywhere.

Since I am just running with default settings of lagom, I thought it should work out of the box. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use version 3.0.0 of sbteclispe:

http://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.0.x/IDEs.html

The issue you're seeing has been fixed on master, but we are waiting for a new sbteclispe release.